# program crashes after 2 inputs

Tags: c++, arrays, void

this program will compile and everything but after typing 2 inputs, it will crash
it's only 2 inputs, not 1, not 3, only 2 and it happens every time.

I'm trying to use inputs to fill an array then I want to use my first array to fill in the first array of my multidimensional array

```
     #include <iostream>
const int COUNTER_NUMBER = 10;

void insert_array(int input[], int outputa[][COUNTER_NUMBER], int&number_vars);


int main()
{   
    using namespace std;
    int index1, index2, next, number_vars;
    int inputa[50];
    int outputa[50][COUNTER_NUMBER];
    cout << "type numbers you would like to input up to 50 inputs, press n if you would like to end\n";
    int index = 0;
    cin >> next;
    while ((next != 'n') && (index < 50))
    {
        inputa[index] = next;
        index++;
        cin >> next;
        index = number_vars;
    }
    insert_array(inputa, outputa, number_vars);

return 0;
}

void insert_array(int inputa[], int outputa[][COUNTER_NUMBER], int& number_vars)
{
    int index1 = 0;
    int index = 0;
    int inputb = 0;
    for (index1 = 0; index1 < number_vars; index1++)
    {
        for (index = 0; index < number_vars; index++)
        inputa[index] = inputb;
        inputb = outputa[index1][COUNTER_NUMBER];
    }
}
```

Comment: First correct your while loop

Comment: Why `index++;` if you also have `index = number_vars;`?

Comment: what inputs u r giving.. plz provide.. it's not crashing for me with the inputs given.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
index = number_vars;
```

You haven't initialized `number_vars`. So the next time you try to access `index` you will get Undefined Behaviour.

**I guess you meant it to be the other way round**.

```
number_vars = index;
```

EDIT:
Looking at your code, you don't need the variable `index` at all. Just use `number_vars` instead of `index` (initialized to 0 and incremented on every read operation).

Comment: ...and this could be moved to after the loop finishes.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yes, in fact you don't need two variables at all. Just use number_vars instead of index.